# How to return the result of an equation in simplest radical form in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, math

I'm making a program that gets the sizes of two legs from a triangle from the user (via two text fields) and the program calculates the hypotenuse for them (using the pythagorean theorem). At this point it returns a decimal value. Is there a function that returns the result of the equation in simplest radical form?

Here's my code:

```
-(void)calculateHypotenuse{

legA = [[legATextField text] floatValue];
legB = [[legBTextField text] floatValue];

if (legATextField.text == nil && legBTextField.text == nil) {
    legA = 0;
    legB = 0;
}

hypotenuse = sqrtf(powf(legA, 2) + powf(legB, 2));

hypotenuseLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hypotenuse: %g", hypotenuse];
```

}

Comment: Can you give some representative examples of input and expected output? What output would you expect for a=1.234 and b=2.345 ?

Comment: In the program I am restricting the use of floating-point numbers by not making the decimal point available to the user in the keyboard displayed...

Comment: OK, but could you give some examples to clarify what the "simplest radical form" is?

Comment: @MartinR I think he wants to show √12 as 2√3 instead of 3.46410.

Comment: If you would put in the numbers a=4 and b=6 I would like the output to be: 2√13 instead of 7.2111.....

Comment: There is no built-in function. First you have to compute x = a*a+b*b (using integer arithmetic, not floating point). Then you have to find a representation x = u*u*v where v is "square free". This can be done with the prime number decomposition. Then the answer is c = u√v. – So this is more a mathematical than a programming question.

Comment: Ok... I can do that... I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way before I got knee-deep into the math... Thanks!